# What is the right way to synchronize Laravel model with an external API data sources?

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent, synchronization

*I would like to hear your tips or solutions to this problem. Even more helpful would be links to some working!! open source projects which implements some of these mechanisms.*

For example i want to synchronize all github's gist with Laravel model. I think about two form.

### Option 1

Write separate classes for example Importer and call it's method from controllers and commands and interact with Model.

### Option 2

Put data extracting logic (api calls) inside Laravel's model hierarchy (traits,interfaces and so) and within  artisan's command let's say synchronize:all loop through all model and check for any changes and update each row.

#### example

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Sample\Http\Client;

class Gist extends Model
{
    /**
    * Example of fetching new gists
    */
    public static function getNew($gistId = '6cad326836d38bd3a7ae')
    {
      $resposne = Client::request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/gists/'.$gistId)
        ->response()
        ->json();

      $Gist = new static($response);
      $Gist->save();

      return $Gist;
    }

    /**
    * Get list of all gist from external source and ... who knows
    */
    public function listAllGistFromApi()
    {
      $resposne = Client::request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/gists/')
        ->response()
        ->json();

        return $response;
    }

    /**
    * Example of updating existing gist
    */
    public function updateFromApi()
    {
      $gistId = $this->id; // primary key also api uid

      $resposne = Client::request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/gists/'.$gistId)
        ->response()
        ->json();

      return $this->setAttributes($response)->save(); // simplified logic
    }
}
```

### Your solutions...

Comment: I don't need stackoverflow's code. What I want is your ideas about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `observers`, what it does? it keeps an eye on the model changes, there you can perform your Apis to the out data source, take a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#observers) how to apply `observes` in `Laravel`

Comment: Yes, but It has little problem. I don't know how to force github to subscribe to my observer and notify me whenever they change their gist. (in context of this example). Only way is to regularly call api endpoints compare with my model. How to do that? Where to put this logic?

Comment: i think your can use `webhooks`, and github has that. when a change happens it will make an api call to your backend, so you can handle the changes